# Data Point On Chart MouseOver

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

I'm Using Spline Chart in my winforms Application  i Can Plot Values On chart Easily But I want to add one more feture to Cahrt ,Like Showing Point(dot) On Chart Curve On mouseover to the chart ,Is There an method available using chart ??

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Of What ?? In Microsoft Site They Shows only How To Add Value,Charts ,series etc.

Comment: Really? [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can You Suggest Me Which Thing I Refer ?

Comment: What I suggest you do is: 1. Learn how to look up/read the documentation of the types you're working with. 2. Try create a solution to you problem.  3. If you run into problems with your solution, post the code to SO. 4. Navigate to a tutorial site like [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/).

Comment: Okay, you _might_ want to start looking into the `Chart.PostPaint` and `Chart.PrePaint` events.